# File Exist and catch all searchs

Tags: php, file

I'm trying to find if a file exists. I know the name of it but I do not know the extension. What could I do PHP wise so that the file exists function checks for the file without knowing it's extension?

```
file_exists('image_storage/ses_' . $session_user_id . 'need to put something here for the 
extension' );
```

Comment: [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use PHP's [`glob`](http://php.net/glob) function to get a list of files that match a given pattern:

```
$files = glob('image_storage/ses_' . $session_user_id . '.*');
if (count($files) > 0) {
    // check your files with a loop
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        // do whatever you want; this file exists =]
    }
}
```

You won't need to check if the file exists with `glob`; if it returns it in the array, it should exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in linux you can do this..

```
$ret = exec("ls image_storage/ses_" . $session_user_id."*");
if(!empty($ret))
{
  //file exists..
}
```